# Copy an iterator by list()

Tags: python

I have a question about iterators in python. Code is taken from a book and this example is a bit tricky for me

```
it = read_visits('/tmp/my_numbers.txt')
print(list(it))
print(list(it)) # Already exhausted
```

Here we have an error which occurs because of iterator already exhausted by first print

```
def normalize_copy(numbers):
    numbers = list(numbers) # Copy the iterator
    total = sum(numbers)
    result = []
    for value in numbers:
        percent = 100 * value / total
        result.append(percent)
    return result

it = read_visits(‘/tmp/my_numbers.txt’)
percentages = normalize_copy(it)
print(percentages)
```

Now this example works fine. We have copy of iterator, ok. But this line

```
list(numbers)
```

is equal for both examples... Why first example doesnt work?

Comment: In the second example, `numbers` goes from being an iterator to a normal `list` at the second line in the function. You can iterate over a list however many times you want.

Comment: rdas, right... thanks

Comment: For reference, Effective Python Item 17: https://effectivepython.com/2015/01/03/be-defensive-when-iterating-over-arguments/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither example makes a copy of the *iterator*.  The first one steps through the iterator with the first `print` -- it makes a list, prints the list, and moves on.

The second `print` also tries to convert the iterator production to a list, but the iterator was exhausted by the first `list` conversion; you get an error.

In the second example, you likewise convert the iterator contents to a `list`.  However, instead of piping that list to stdout and discarding it, you save the list as variable `numbers`.  This is a list, not an iterator.  Thus, you can refer to it as many times as you like, according to the properties of class `list`.

Using an iterator is comparable to reading a file: once you read through the entire file, another read attempt will fail ... until you reset the file descriptor somehow.

Does that help clear up the functionality?